# Static Page on Category Main page to show sub categories ina grid with images

Tags: magento, navigation, static-block

With the help of an online tutorial, I am trying to create a static block showing subcategories (Swing Seats ... Weathercovers ) in a grid on a main category page (Garden).  I have copied and amended the Navigation.php into the local folder and also created a subcategory_listing.phtml in the same location.

but ...

Help! I am receiving the following error ... Can anyone help me???

Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in....... /template/catalog/navigation/subcategory_listing.phtml on line 5

In the subcategory_listing.phtml file I have in the first few lines ...

```
   <div class="category-products">
<ul class="products-grid">
<?php
$_categories=$this->getCurrentChildCategories();
if($_categories->count()):
$categorycount = 0;
foreach ($_categories as $_category):
if($_category->getIsActive()):
$cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);
$catName = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getName();
if ($categorycount == 0){
$class = "first";
}
elseif ($categorycount == 3){
$class = "last";
}
else{
$class = "";
}
?>
<li class="item <?=$class?>">
<a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $_category->getImageUrl() ?>" width="100" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>" /></a>
<h2><a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a></h2>
</li>
<?php
endif;
if($categorycount == 3){
$categorycount = 0;
echo "</ul>\n\n<ul class=\"products-grid\">";
}
else{
$categorycount++;
}
endforeach;
endif;
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is the code I am using in the Navigation.php

```
   <?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Catalog
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */


/**
 * Catalog navigation
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Catalog
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    /**
     * Category instance
     *
     * @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Category
     */
    protected $_categoryInstance;

    /**
     * Current category key
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_currentCategoryKey;

    /**
     * Array of level position counters
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_itemLevelPositions = array();

    /**
     * Current child categories collection
     *
     * @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection
     */
    protected $_currentChildCategories;

    /**
     * Set cache data
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->addData(array('cache_lifetime' => false));
        $this->addCacheTag(array(
            Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::CACHE_TAG,
            Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group::CACHE_TAG
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Get Key pieces for caching block content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        $shortCacheId = array(
            'CATALOG_NAVIGATION',
            Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
            Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName(),
            Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('template'),
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(),
            'template' => $this->getTemplate(),
            'name' => $this->getNameInLayout(),
            $this->getCurrenCategoryKey()
        );
        $cacheId = $shortCacheId;

        $shortCacheId = array_values($shortCacheId);
        $shortCacheId = implode('|', $shortCacheId);
        $shortCacheId = md5($shortCacheId);

        $cacheId['category_path'] = $this->getCurrenCategoryKey();
        $cacheId['short_cache_id'] = $shortCacheId;

        return $cacheId;
    }

    /**
     * Get current category key
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCurrenCategoryKey()
    {
        if (!$this->_currentCategoryKey) {
            $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
            if ($category) {
                $this->_currentCategoryKey = $category->getPath();
            } else {
                $this->_currentCategoryKey = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
            }
        }

        return $this->_currentCategoryKey;
    }

    /**
     * Get categories of current store
     *
     * @return Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection
     */
    public function getStoreCategories()
    {
        $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
        return $helper->getStoreCategories();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve child categories of current category
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection
     */
public function getCurrentChildCategories()
   {
        $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
        $category   = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
        /* @var $category Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
        /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Collection */
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('is_anchor')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail') 
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
            ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
            ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
            ->joinUrlRewrite()
            ->load();

        $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $layer->prepareProductCollection($productCollection);
        $productCollection->addCountToCategories($collection);
        return $collection;
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get this to work?

Many thanks

Comment: Could you post again your FULL code for the subcategory_listing.phtml ? Thanks

Comment: OK.  Edited the code above to show the entire subcategory_listing.phtml

Comment: looks like your $this->getCurrentChildCategories() is returning with nothing. What you modified in the Navigation.php? Could you post that one also?

Comment: Edited the original post to show the navigation.php file.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you confirm thats the exact contant? As I see after the getCurrentChildCategories function a html code there, what will definitely break ...

Comment: That is the code.  Have I got two files in one ?  Have I put both the subcategory_listing.phtml into the navigation.php?

Comment: I have copied the files again from scratch and reedited the above post again to show both files.

Comment: Hmm, I still think you not psted it correctly, because now it missing the  bototm parts, if theer is any. Anyway, I would recommend to follow this tutorial, as this doesn't request to override the core navigation.php. http://www.creare.co.uk/magento-subcategories-category-pages

Comment: That worked great ... thank you!  Any idea where I put the CSS styling for this static block?

Comment: Any idea how to now get the subcategories in a grid rather than a list?